# Get Nickname/Username using jid from Samck

Tags: xmpp, smack

Using Smack, how I can get Nickname/Username from JID using Smake.

Note, the JID is not in my roaster.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May be its too late but for others who are facing this issue 
From smack:4.2.0

You can get all parts separately using JID.

if you have JID like abcd@xyzPc- 599

```
String local = XmppStringUtils.parseLocalpart(userObject.getUserId().toString());

Log.d(TAG, local); // print abcd

String domain = XmppStringUtils.parseDomain(userObject.getUserId().toString());

Log.d(TAG, domain); // print xyzPc-599
```

You can check code for [XmppStringUtils](https://github.com/igniterealtime/jxmpp/blob/master/jxmpp-core/src/main/java/org/jxmpp/util/XmppStringUtils.java).

Hope will help to someone...

Answer (score 0):

Use the String Utils of Smack to parse the name portion of the JID

[Smack Docs String Utils](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/util/StringUtils.html)

```
String name = StringUtils.parseName(JID);
```

WHen you say it's not in your Roster, how are you being passed the JID? Are you getting it from your message?

Answer (score 0):

we can get nick name using JID but we must add all users in VCARD

```
String nickname = smackHelper.getNickname(from);


public String getNickname(String jid) throws SmackInvocationException {
    VCard vCard = vCardHelper.loadVCard(jid);

    return vCard.getNickName();
}


public VCard loadVCard(String jid) throws SmackInvocationException {
    VCard vCard = new VCard();
    try {
        vCard.load(con, jid);

        return vCard;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SmackInvocationException(e);
    }
}
```